# Debugging using RealView Debug(RVDebug)

Tags: debugging, realview

I have some C code for an ARM926 target. I am trying to debug it using "Arm Xtended Debugger" (AXD).  The `main()` of this code, takes 14 command line arguments which are mentioned in the code warrior project settings at proper place and behavior of the code is as expected.

But when I try to use the same AXF (Arm eXecutable Format file) file and try to do source level debugging using the RVDEBUG by changing the settings of the Codewarrior project, and start debugging, then the argc value is 1.  Then the behavior of the code is unexpected.

When I select RVDEBUG in code warrior settings I give the same options as I used during AXD debug session.

So my question is:

I am using the same AXD for both the debugging sessions(AXD and RVDEBUG), why are they behaving differently?  They should behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use CodeWarrior but I know AXD and RVD: I remember Code Warrior can invoke AXD with the suitable arguments for the image, and so on. I don't know if Code Warrior can invoke RVD as well. So I suppose you run RVD yourself, outside any Code Warrior menu, don't you?
Then you just have to add the arguments in the dedicated input box at the bottom of the Load Image menu.

If this still does not work, I suggest you have a look at the semihosting options (they're rather in the connections options of RVD than in Code Warrior's).

Good luck!